# Show $f(x) = x^2$ lipschitz on $[0,1]$

Tags: continuity

I would like to show this result but I am a bit stuck

To show $f(x)$ is lipschitz, show:

$$|x^2 - y^2| \leq L |x-y| \quad \forall x,y \in [0,1]$$

Proceed as usual:

$|x^2 - y^2| = |x-y||x+y|$

But what is $|x+y|?$

Comment: Just bound $|x+y|$ on $[0,1]$. Since this is increasing, it is bounded above by 2.

Comment: Alternatively, mean value theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $|x+y| \leq |x|+|y|$. Can you continue the last step?

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should take $x = 1,  y= 1$ to get a bound of 2? But wouldn't that make $|x-y|$ part go to zero?

Comment: You need to keep $|x-y|$,and bound the $|x+y|$

Comment: Can you explain what it means to keep $|x-y|$ but bound $|x+y|$